# graphql node api: how can I define a field as optional?

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

GraphQL allows you to specify whether a field is to be optional or not (add `!`)

Using the Node API, I cannot find that option.

see https://graphql.org/graphql-js/constructing-types/

I also went through the types without luck

see https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/main/src/index.ts

What am I missing?

I basically want

```
type MyEntity {
  uuid: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

instead of

```
type MyEntity {
  uuid: ID
  name: String
}
```

Comment: optional=nullable, required .... like graphqlNotNull( type )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer

```
const preType:GraphQLOutputType = GraphQLInt;
// wrap the type with `GraphQLNonNull`
const type = new GraphQLNonNull(preType);
```

see https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/main/src/type/definition.ts#L391